# child xml nodes reading issues

Tags: c#, xml

need help to read xml file. i have one xml file which i want to read and store in data base below is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
  <SctiesSttlmTxStsAdvc>
    <Id>
      <Id>ACK0000000000004</Id>
        <CreDtTm>
                <Dt>2011-08-26</Dt> 
        </CreDtTm>
    </Id>
    <TxId>
      <AcctOwnrTxId>TCP-CMF001-000000004</AcctOwnrTxId>
    </TxId>
    <PrcgSts>
      <AckdAccptd>
        <NoSpcfdRsn>NORE</NoSpcfdRsn>
      </AckdAccptd>
    </PrcgSts>
    <MsgOrgtr>
      <PrtryId>
        <Id>068001</Id>
        <Issr>BMSC</Issr>
      </PrtryId>
    </MsgOrgtr>
    <MsgRcpt>
      <PrtryId>
        <Id>056001</Id>
        <Issr>BMSC</Issr>
      </PrtryId>
    </MsgRcpt>
  </SctiesSttlmTxStsAdvc>
  <SctiesSttlmTxStsAdvc>
  </SctiesSttlmTxStsAdvc>
</Document>
```

above xml contains  tags which occur multiple time and i need to find out the value of all child node which has value

Comment: You could load the XML in memory using LINQ to XML (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) and just enumerate the child nodes.

Comment: its a framework 1.1 so i can not use any new dot net component i had tried to load xml in in doc.LoadXML and got an error System.Xml.XmlException: The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1 also the xml file gng to b big. xml file will contain <SctiesSttlmTxStsAdvc>
  </SctiesSttlmTxStsAdvc> multiple time and i have to read the child node value between the above tags n store in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I think it should get you all the child nodes from your root node 


 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("nameofyourfile.xml");

        XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;

        //Display the contents of the child nodes.
        if (root.HasChildNodes)
        {
          for (int i=0; i<root.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
          {
             if(root.ChildNodes[i].InnerText!="")
             {
            Console.WriteLine(root.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
                }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

you can load xm directly like this

```
 doc.LoadXml(<Document>
  <SctiesSttlmTxStsAdvc>
    <Id>
      <Id>ACK0000000000004</Id>
        <CreDtTm>
                <Dt>2011-08-26</Dt> 
        </CreDtTm>
    </Id>
    <TxId>
      <AcctOwnrTxId>TCP-CMF001-000000004</AcctOwnrTxId>
    </TxId>
    <PrcgSts>
      <AckdAccptd>
        <NoSpcfdRsn>NORE</NoSpcfdRsn>
      </AckdAccptd>
    </PrcgSts>
    <MsgOrgtr>
      <PrtryId>
        <Id>068001</Id>
        <Issr>BMSC</Issr>
      </PrtryId>
    </MsgOrgtr>
    <MsgRcpt>
      <PrtryId>
        <Id>056001</Id>
        <Issr>BMSC</Issr>
      </PrtryId>
    </MsgRcpt>
  </SctiesSttlmTxStsAdvc>
  <SctiesSttlmTxStsAdvc>
  </SctiesSttlmTxStsAdvc>
</Document>);
```

Comment: Hi Cold Told, thank u for yr reply after applying above code i m getting a below error  System.Xml.XmlException: The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. when i m doing xmldoc.LoadXML(path)

Comment: you can do like in the load but whole document

Comment: hi..finally i have got my output i used xmltextreader and read textelement by checking with nodetype 
thanks for reply ...every one :)